# Excel, use user input in cell formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to write a new spreadsheet,and I want a cell to use data the user has put in, in a formula. Is this possible and if so how?
This is the formula I would like to use, where the ... is the data the user  has put in =...*C8.
The formula and the user input would Idealy be in the same cell.
Hopefully Ihave been clear.

Looking forwards for your answers

Comment: Hi @ Job Van den Berghe ,, read the comment below help U,, no VBA need !!

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, this can't be done. Let me explain:

A cell content is either a formula or a value, not both.

On one hand, if you used a value, that would be it; you would not be able to multiply it by C8.

On the other hand, if you used a formula, you would cause a reference loop. If you write =A8*C8 in A8 it would not make sense. What would be the result for the A8 part of the formula? It would be A8*C8 once again, and same question, and so on, and so on.

Even if we assume you had a special keyword to avoid self-reference, say, "...", writing into the cell would imply replacing the contents: by entering a value you would replace the formula with the value.

Comment: Hmm thats what I feared, could this be done using VB?

Comment: I think it's doable. You would lose the original cell input after you enter the final value after multiplication, though, but maybe that's acceptable for you.

Comment: Hi @alvarezp,, if you write `A8*C8` in cell A8 then you get prompt message about "Circular references",, and as soon you press Enter or hit Ok in A8 you get ZERO. If in Excel U wanna to use cell it self in the formula so U need to activate the ITERATION,,, and then after if U use formula in A8,,, `=A8*C8` and suppose C8 has 10 then first result will `10` ,, then after every time U press F9 to recalculate the Formula in A8,, Excel will multiply the last value in A8 with C8. For example 1st `0*10` you get 10 then 2nd `10*10` = 100 and so on.

Comment: **Cont..**  Activate ITERATION ,, File--Option--Formula and check Enable Iteration,,, by default is 1.